# How to translate the Laravel pagination?

Tags: laravel, pagination, translation

I'm building a Laravel application that supports multiple languages. All was going OK but now i'm facing problem translating the pagination display numbers. I have tried to search for solution but don't find any. Any simple demonstration will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I think its help you : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 6):

you can publish the pagination views into your project, use the php artisan command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

this artisan command create a new folder and files in

> resources/views/vendor/pagination

see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view
for more details

Answer (score 3):

you can [customize](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) your view by creating views like pagination.blade.php and use

```
{{ $paginator->links('pagination') }}
```

for format your numbers in any language numerals like Bengali you can add a helper method like this in helper file:

```
function toBengaliNum($number)
{
    $number = str_replace("1", "১", $number);
    $number = str_replace("2", "২", $number);
    $number = str_replace("3", "৩", $number);
    $number = str_replace("4", "৪", $number);
    $number = str_replace("5", "৫", $number);
    $number = str_replace("6", "৬", $number);
    $number = str_replace("7", "৭", $number);
    $number = str_replace("8", "৮", $number);
    $number = str_replace("9", "৯", $number);
    $number = str_replace("0", "০", $number);
    return $number;
}
```

and in your pagination.blade.php file use this helper method to format numbers like:

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $url }}">{{ toBengaliNum($page) }}</a></li>
```